# Emacs python.el: ipython cells are advanced by completion

Tags: python, emacs, ipython

I've been trying to find a way to effectively combine Emacs and IPython for scientific python programming.  The python.el included in Emacs 24.4 has solid IPython support (using IPython within Emacs, sending lines and buffers, etc.).  However, one small problem I'm having is that the IPython cell number (displayed in the prompts) advances when completion is invoked in either the python buffer or the inferior python buffer.  Here is a simple example:

```
In [42]: x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 5)

In [43]: x
Out[43]: array([-1. , -0.5,  0. ,  0.5,  1. ])

In [44]: y = np.sin(x)

In [47]: y
Out[47]: array([-0.84147098, -0.47942554,  0.        ,  0.47942554,  0.84147098])

In [48]: _45
Out[48]: 'np.sin;np.sinc;np.single;np.singlecomplex;np.sinh'

In [49]: _46
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-93c8f2e58170> in <module>()
----> 1 _46

NameError: name '_46' is not defined
```

where `<tab>` was hit after the 'n' in `np.sin(x)` to invoke completions.  This causes the cell number to skip from 44 to 47 for the next command.  Is there any workaround for this?  I tried searching the web and I couldn't turn up any mention of this issue or how to fix it.

Thanks!!